# AngularJS directive not being rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make a simple AngularJS directive but it's not showing.

### index.html w/ AngularJS Script Inline

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Angular Sample </title>
</head>
<body ng-app="demo" ng-controller="HomeController">

    <data-table data="collection"></data-table>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('demo', []);
        app.controller('HomeController', function ( $scope ) {
            $scope.collection = [
                { Experiment: 'CMS', 'LHC experiment ?': 'Yes', Type: 'General' },
                { Experiment: 'ATLAS', 'LHC experiment ?': 'Yes', Type: 'General' },
                { Experiment: 'LHCb', 'LHC experiment ?': 'Yes', Type: 'Specific' },
                { Experiment: 'ALICE', 'LHC experiment ?': 'Yes', Type: 'Specific' }
            ];
        });

        app.directive('dataTable', function(){
            // The directive consists on an object that this function should return
            return {
                restrict: 'E', // define how the directive will be used
                // 'E' for element, 'A' for attribute and 'C' for class
                // 'EA' means element or attribute 
                templateUrl: 'data-table.html', // the template file
                // if specified, the content of the HTML element to which the directive
                // is applied will be overitten by this template
                scope: { // contains the data passed to the directive as attributes
                    data: '='
                },
                // This function is executed when the directive is rendered
                link: function(scope){
                    // scope.data will refer the data passed to the directive
                    // Defining titles of the table as the properties of the first
                    // object in data, as we assume all objects have the same properties
                    scope.titles = [];
                    if(scope.data != undefined && scope.data.length > 0){
                        for(attr in scope.data[0]){
                            scope.titles.push(attr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### data-table.html (in the same directory as index.html)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <!-- We assume that the list of titles will be declared -->
        <th ng-repeat="title in titles"> {{ title }} </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- We assume that data is the collection of objects -->
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
            <td ng-repeat="title in titles"> {{ item[title] }} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am browsing to the page using Apache ( localhost/../index.html ) so angular should be able to load the template using AJAX.

[Here is the code at Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UjepKxK6sWii0CALnqJC)

Comment: @RameshRajendran in the index.html, right after the body tag I have `<data-table data="collection"></data-table>`

Comment: `<data-data-table data="collection"></data-data-table>`

Answer (score 3):

You have to rename the directive element... somehow the "data-" prefix messes things up and "dataTable" is not recognized by angular...